# Named message params

Tags: java, messageformat

I was often using `MessageFormat` for indexed params in situations like this:

```
String text = MessageFormat.format("The goal is {0} points.", 5);
```

Now I encountered a situation where I need to handle messages which are in the following format:

```
"The {title} is {number} points."
```

So, values are not indexed anymore and placeholders are strings. How can I handle this situation and have the same functionality like with `MessageFormat`? `MessageFormat` throws parse exception if params are not indexed.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you considered using [Apache Velocity](http://velocity.apache.org/)?

Comment: Have you tried to pass two arguments?
`MessageFormat.format("The {0} is {1} points.", title, number);`

Comment: @LBechir, Thank you for your answer but the question is not about the number of params. It's about indexed and named params :) I have named params instead of 0 and 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple suggestion would consist of replacing the text parameter as index with a regex match and then use it as you would normally. Here an example :

```
int paramIndex = 0;

String text = "The {title} is {number} points.";
String paramRegex = "\\{(.*?)\\}";
Pattern paramPattern = Pattern.compile(paramRegex);
Matcher matcher = paramPattern.matcher(text);

while(matcher.find())
    text = text.replace(matcher.group(), "{" + paramIndex++ + "}");

text = MessageFormat.format(text, "kick", "3");
```

In that case, `text` would be equals to "The kick is 3 points" at the end.

Comment: Thank you. This looks promising :)